# Understanding bindonce limitations

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, bindonce

I've been reading about [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) as a way of reducing watches and enhance performance. In an effort to better understand the package i made an example with `ng-repeat`.

[JSBIN here](http://jsbin.com/xokaxozi/1/edit)

Without `bindonce` I'm getting 103 watches, 100 list items + 2 buttons.

Using `bindonce` i'm getting 3 watches, 2 bottons + 1 fort the list.

If I understood `binonce` correctly, it removes the watch once the binded object is resolved and rendered. So,

**How is it possible that using `bindonce`, changes made to the object are still reflected in the DOM ?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a hint in the documentation:

`Now this example uses 0 watches per person and renders exactly the same result as the above that uses ng-. *(Angular still uses 1 watcher for ngRepeatWatch)`

The key is that Angular still keeps a watch on `ngRepeat`, so if the array changes `ngRepeat` will re-render the array and the `bindonce` functionality is re-applied.

I've updated your [jsbin example here](http://jsbin.com/xugemico/2/edit) to better illustrate this http://jsbin.com/xugemico/2/edit

Notice the following addition:

```
<p>
  Bindonce: first item: 
  <span bindonce="arr" bo-bind="arr[0]"></span>
</p>
```

The above code utilizes `bindonce` on the first array item without ngRepeat's watch in play, you'll see that the value is not updated as per the bindonce inside ngRepeat.